# Using ContextAPI doesn't re-render its consumer, but content is changed. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-context

Consider this little example. I did some experiments with Context API while learning through the book.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(0);

const D3 = () => {
    console.log('render D3');
    return <MyContext.Consumer>{num => `${num}`}</MyContext.Consumer>;
};

const D2 = React.memo(() => {
    console.log('render D2');
    return <D3 />;
});

const D1 = React.memo(() => {
    console.log('render D1');
    return <D2 />;
});

const App = () => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

    console.log('render App');
  return (
    <div>
      <MyContext.Provider value={num}>
        <D1 />
      </MyContext.Provider>
      <input type='button' onClick={() => { setNum(Math.random()) }} />
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

As I click the button, I can see my tiny number is changing. Also notice that `App` is rendered for each click while `D1`, `D2` are not. I understood the reason of this.

But weird thing is, when button is clicked, `D3` hasn't been re-rendered! Still its content is changing. What happened exactly?

Please check this for your convinient: https://jsfiddle.net/gfnuko/cs7jpo69/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child `<MyContext.Consumer>` is re-rendered. Do this to see:

```
const D3 = () => {
    console.log('render D3');
    return <MyContext.Consumer>{num => {console.log('CONSUMER'}; return num;}}</MyContext.Consumer>;
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj8op176/)

Comment: So should I think that function inside of <SomeContext.Consumer> can be assumed as another function component?

Comment: @Phryxia No. The function inside of `<MyContext.Consumer>` is part of the provider/consumer pattern and is not itself a component. Notice how this function accepts the value from the provider, not an object like a function component would.